# Image Processing: Algorithm Improvement for 'Coca-Cola Can' Recognition

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing, opencv

One of the most interesting projects I've worked on in the past couple of years was a project about [image processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_processing). The goal was to develop a system to be able to recognize Coca-Cola **'cans'** (note that I'm stressing the word 'cans', you'll see why in a minute). You can see a sample below, with the can recognized in the *green rectangle* with scale and rotation.

[image: Template matching]

Some constraints on the project:

- The background could be very noisy.
- The *can* could have any *scale* or *rotation* or even orientation (within reasonable limits).
- The image could have some degree of fuzziness (contours might not be entirely straight).
- There could be Coca-Cola bottles in the image, and the algorithm should only detect the *can*!
- The brightness of the image could vary a lot (so you can't rely "too much" on color detection).
- The *can* could be partly hidden on the sides or the middle and possibly partly hidden behind a bottle.
- There could be no *can* at all in the image, in which case you had to find nothing and write a message saying so.

So you could end up with tricky things like this (which in this case had my algorithm totally fail):

[image: Total fail]

I did this project a while ago, and had a lot of fun doing it, and I had a decent implementation. Here are some details about my implementation:

**Language**: Done in C++ using [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) library.

**Pre-processing**: For the image pre-processing, i.e. transforming the image into a more raw form to give to the algorithm, I used 2 methods:

1. Changing color domain from RGB to [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and filtering based on "red" hue, saturation above a certain threshold to avoid orange-like colors, and filtering of low value to avoid dark tones. The end result was a binary black and white image, where all white pixels would represent the pixels that match this threshold. Obviously there is still a lot of crap in the image, but this reduces the number of dimensions you have to work with.
   [image: Binarized image]
2. Noise filtering using median filtering (taking the median pixel value of all neighbors and replace the pixel by this value) to reduce noise.
3. Using [Canny Edge Detection Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) to get the contours of all items after 2 precedent steps.
   [image: Contour detection]

**Algorithm**: The algorithm itself I chose for this task was taken from [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123725380) awesome book on feature extraction and called [Generalized Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_Hough_transform) (pretty different from the regular Hough Transform). It basically says a few things:

- You can describe an object in space without knowing its analytical equation (which is the case here).
- It is resistant to image deformations such as scaling and rotation, as it will basically test your image for every combination of scale factor and rotation factor.
- It uses a base model (a template) that the algorithm will "learn".
- Each pixel remaining in the contour image will vote for another pixel which will supposedly be the center (in terms of gravity) of your object, based on what it learned from the model.

In the end, you end up with a heat map of the votes, for example here all the pixels of the contour of the can will vote for its gravitational center, so you'll have a lot of votes in the same pixel corresponding to the center, and will see a peak in the heat map as below:

[image: GHT]

Once you have that, a simple threshold-based heuristic can give you the location of the center pixel, from which you can derive the scale and rotation and then plot your little rectangle around it (final scale and rotation factor will obviously be relative to your original template). In theory at least...

**Results**: Now, while this approach worked in the basic cases, it was severely lacking in some areas:

- It is **extremely slow**! I'm not stressing this enough. Almost a full day was needed to process the 30 test images, obviously because I had a very high scaling factor for rotation and translation, since some of the cans were very small.
- It was completely lost when bottles were in the image, and for some reason almost always found the bottle instead of the can (perhaps because bottles were bigger, thus had more pixels, thus more votes)
- Fuzzy images were also no good, since the votes ended up in pixel at random locations around the center, thus ending with a very noisy heat map.
- In-variance in translation and rotation was achieved, but not in orientation, meaning that a can that was not directly facing the camera objective wasn't recognized.

Can you help me improve my **specific** algorithm, using **exclusively OpenCV** features, to resolve the **four specific** issues mentioned?

I hope some people will also learn something out of it as well, after all I think not only people who ask questions should learn. :)

Comment: It might be said that this question is more appropriate at dsp.stackexchange.com, or stats.stackexchange.com, and you certainly should consider re-asking at those sites too.

Comment: The first thing to do here is to analyze *why* the different failure cases are happening. E.g., isolate examples of places where bottles win, where the images are fuzzy, etc., and perform some statistical analysis to learn the difference between their Hough representations and the ones you wish it would detect. Some great places to learn about alternative approaches are [here](http://www.svcl.ucsd.edu/projects/discriminantsaliency/) and [here](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~lbourdev/poselets/)

Comment: @linker Wouldn't be extracting SIFT or SURF features much faster than the hough-transformation ? Why only detect cans when you could detect more registered objects?

Comment: @stacker makes a good point. For speed you want to get cheap-to-compute features, like histograms of oriented gradients. A really naive first approach would be to manually label a bunch of can rectangles in some training images, and use these plus random negative examples to train an SVM or decision-tree classifier. The training will take longer, but the execution on novel images will be much faster. I'm planning to write this method up when I get more free time to include the right references.

Comment: @stacker I did this because the scope of the assignment was specifically aimed at CocaCola cans. I don't know much about SIFT or SURF, but if this algorithm fits this problem I'd love to see a reply on the topic.

Comment: How about an approach similar to [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore)? ;)

Comment: Why was this moved from [dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2077/algorithm-improvement-for-coca-cola-can-shape-recognition)?  It seems like that site would be an even better fit than stackoverflow o_O

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett reCAPTCHA could be an idea, but you have absolutely no guarantee that the Coca-Cola letters will be visible, they could be totally hidden, partially hidden, or the can could be turned around. And doesn't solve the problem with the bottle either since the letters are the same.

Comment: Have You tried to detect the top or bottom seal of the can? It could be possible to detect it as an edge parallel to the edge of the red area.

Comment: I didn't mean for character recognition, I meant using the idea of using humans to do the finding. I.d. show then 2 pictures, one known and one not known. Was just joking. :-)

Comment: Can you add few more test images to get a much more idea?

Comment: Did you tried it without converting RGB to HSV? I think your problem of bottles is in your conversion, actually you removed your cans in your first step.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri No the conversion to HSV works fine, it's just so I can eliminate some of the stuff that is clearly not red-like. Can and bottle are still there even after passing to HSV, the problem is mainly how to differentiate between the 2 since the have common characteristics.

Comment: But seems your sample is saying something else, I think in your first sample after preprocessing images of can removed? would you arrange your samples step by step?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Oh i see what you mean, images 2 and 3 in my question are not of the same original ! In image 3, there was only a can. I could have posted more, but trying to keep the question to a strict minimum. Just assume that the HSV translation is correctly keeping both can and  bottles (+ some noise all over the image)

Comment: I have a great attraction for this kind of software. Anyone knows if there are some mature and well established Java Library to do these image recognition?

Comment: @EdPichler openCV just very recently released their java bindings for their library (as of 2.4.4). So, basically you could use openCV in java (without all the fuss of doing JNI manually). I tried it and it worked fine (but it's still buggy since its very recent)

Comment: This is all way over my head, but I was thinking: "why not use OpenCV's GPU module and take advantage of your GPU to speed it up dramatically?" OpenCV basically have a GPU module that has algorithms like Hough Transforms and what-not written in CUDA and run on CUDA-enabled GPU's. The great thing here is that there is no need to learn any CUDA. Just import the gpu module and start using it. I hope this helps (it should theoretically increase performance by an order of magnitude or more)

Comment: This is like an obvious application of a convolutional neural network with scale/rotation invariance.

Comment: If you use a hough-transform, you should use a faster version of the original algorithm. You can modify the hough-transform to focus on only high probability parameters using methods like RANSAC.

Comment: Only the information of special red and white in coca-cola is enough distinguishable.

Comment: 1337!  Please, nobody upvote this question again

Comment: This question should be closed for 5 or 6 different reasons, pls click the "Close" button.

Comment: I wonder how this task would be dealt with in 2020 with CNNs going crazy. There are SSD/ YOLO/ Unet type of things, but these primarily deal with larger objects. I wonder if there is an equivalent for small day to day objects like watches, phones toys etc.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett the processing time per frame would be pretty darn long for that approach. ;)

Answer (score 777, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to extract features (keypoints) using the [scale-invariant feature transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) (SIFT) or [Speeded Up Robust Features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeded_up_robust_features) (SURF).

You can find a nice `OpenCV` code example in `Java`, `C++`, and `Python` on this page: *[Features2D + Homography to find a known object](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dff/tutorial_feature_homography.html)*

Both algorithms are invariant to scaling and rotation. Since they work with features, you can also handle [occlusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_occlusion) (as long as enough keypoints are visible).

[image]

Image source: tutorial example

The processing takes a few hundred ms for SIFT, SURF is bit faster, but it not suitable for real-time applications. ORB uses FAST which is weaker regarding rotation invariance.

#### The original papers

- [SURF: Speeded Up Robust Features](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/%7Esurf/eccv06.pdf)
- [Distinctive Image Features
  from Scale-Invariant Keypoints](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Elowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf)
- [ORB: an efficient alternative to SIFT or SURF](http://www.willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/orb_final.pdf)

Comment: Sounds interesting. Does this algorithm also handle orientation invariance (i.e. if the can doesn't directly face the objective of the camera)? This is one of the major points where my algorithm failed.

Comment: @linker you could take a few pictures of the 3D-object by rotating (around objects y-axis) Sinceimages of a can look different from front and backside you would try to find the closest match and estimate its orientation regarding cases where the logo isn't fully visible.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to apply this algorithm in case of randomly sampled images, where I just have a plain jpeg or png image. Would this algorithm still work in this case, or do I need some special images?

Comment: Could you provide an example in your answer on how to use it with OpenCV? That would be way cool !

Comment: @linker I tried to run it using your images, but the coke can in the scene image was probably too small (maybe a higher resolution would work) to extract enough features. If you have trouble with the features change the `minHessian` parameter (Step 1).

Comment: Excellent post, thanks for the details ! Yes I've intentionnally reduces the size of the images here to reduce bandwidth, but my original images have much better quality. I'll give this a try, but sounds like exactly what it's made for and much simpler than the GHT.

Comment: I agree with @stacker - SIFT is an excellent choice.  It's very robust against scale and rotation operations. It 's somewhat robust against perspective deformation (this can be improved as suggested by stacker: a template database with different perspective views of the desired object).  Its Achilles' heel in my experience would be strong lighting variations and very expensive computation. I don't know of any Java implementations. I'm aware of an OpenCV implementation and have used a GPU c++/Windows ([SiftGPU](http://cs.unc.edu/~ccwu/siftgpu/)) implementation suitable for realtime performance.

Comment: A note of warning: as much as I love SIFT/SURF and what they have done to me, they are patent encumbered. This *might* be a problem, depending on a number of conditions including geographic location AFAIK.

Comment: A potential problem could be that it may generate false positives whereever there is the Coca-Cola logo.

Comment: So try OpenCV's ORB or FREAK which have no patent issues. ORB is much faster than SIFT. ORB it is a bit poor with scale and light variations in my experience but test it yourself.

Comment: How can you accept this as an answer... None of the feature descriptors can differentiate bottles from a cans.. They all just view invariant local pattern descriptors. I agree that SIFT,SURF,ORB,FREAK etc. can help you in feature matching but.. What about your other parts of the question like occlusions, Bottle vs Can etc. I hope this is not a complete solution in fact if you would have GOOGLED your problem probably the first result would be this answer only.

Comment: @G453 you are absolutely right! Probably he was fascinated by the performance of SHIFT and forgot that feature extraction and matching was NOT THE PROBLEM...

Comment: I also agree with @G453, but I think feature matching is still the best starting point. About occlusions, feature matching will have some degree of robustness, 1/3 of the Cola logo visible might be enough for the detection. To filter only the cans cans I would probably do something like Back Projection to detect the metal, I see no other way around using cans distinctive color features. Other than that, maybe its geometry.

Comment: To me a very important salient feature is the top part of the can, it's metallic color and curvature.

Comment: Though i agree  with @G453 . I also feel that since the OP did not explore this path. His problem has not become exponentially easier to solve. Since the answer provided has taken OP in the right direction i feel it is a good answer. Also once OP finds the SIFT descriptor its only a matter of time before he figures out how to find rotation of the object and hence estimating the location and orientation of the can .

Comment: What about the state of the art of object detection? using CNN you can extract specific features and train a network to process it to obtain the bounding box and the objectness. However. the most challenging task of this problem is the classification between cans and bottles and the only thing that I can think to address this problem is using Structure from motion to reconstruct the volume, therefore, get 3D information.

Comment: Mirror for link [Features2D + Homography to find a known object](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html)

Comment: For cans V bottles obviously they are **totally different objects**, you just train it for two different things.  (You might as well say "how to make it recognize both motorbikes and SUVs as vehicles?!", nonsensical.)

Comment: This answer is just a comment ("try using SIFT").

Comment: The opencv **example doesn't work right out of the box** for non-flat surfaces like a can of coke. creating a bounding box of the picture depends on `findHomography` thus assumes the object is a plane, and it works between two plane(also works for relatively similar to planes.)

Answer (score 445):

To speed things up, I would take advantage of the fact that you are not asked to find an arbitrary image/object, but specifically one with the Coca-Cola logo. This is significant because this logo is very distinctive, and it should have a characteristic, scale-invariant signature in the frequency domain, particularly in the red channel of RGB. That is to say, the alternating pattern of red-to-white-to-red encountered by a horizontal scan line (trained on a horizontally aligned logo) will have a distinctive "rhythm" as it passes through the central axis of the logo. That rhythm will "speed up" or "slow down" at different scales and orientations, but will remain proportionally equivalent. You could identify/define a few dozen such scanlines, both horizontally and vertically through the logo and several more diagonally, in a starburst pattern. Call these the "signature scan lines."

[image: Signature scan line]

Searching for this signature in the target image is a simple matter of scanning the image in horizontal strips. Look for a high-frequency in the red-channel (indicating moving from a red region to a white one), and once found, see if it is followed by one of the frequency rhythms identified in the training session. Once a match is found, you will instantly know the scan-line's orientation and location in the logo (if you keep track of those things during training), so identifying the boundaries of the logo from there is trivial.

I would be surprised if this weren't a linearly-efficient algorithm, or nearly so. It obviously doesn't address your can-bottle discrimination, but at least you'll have your logos.

(Update: for bottle recognition I would look for coke (the brown liquid) adjacent to the logo --  that is, *inside* the bottle. Or, in the case of an empty bottle, I would look for a *cap* which will always have the same basic shape, size, and distance from the logo and will typically be all white or red. Search for a solid color eliptical shape where a cap *should* be, relative to the logo. Not foolproof of course, but your goal here should be to find the *easy* ones *fast*.)

(It's been a few years since my image processing days, so I kept this suggestion high-level and conceptual. I think it might slightly approximate how a human eye might operate -- or at least how my brain does!)

Comment: That's a great suggestion, I especially like the fact that this algorithm should be pretty fast, even if it will probably have many false negatives. One of my hidden goals is to use this detection in real-time for robotics, so that could be a good compromise !

Comment: Yes, it is often forgotten (in a field characterized by precision) that *approximation* algorithms are essential for most real-time, real-world-modeling tasks. (I based my [thesis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.163.2733) on this concept.) Save your time-demanding algorithms for limited regions (to prune false positives). And remember: in robotics you're usually not limited to a single image. Assuming a mobile robot, a fast alg can search dozens of images from different angles in less time than sophisticated algs spend on one, significantly reducing false negatives.

Comment: I like the idea of using what amounts to a barcode scanner for **extremely fast** detection of Coca-Cola logos. +1!

Comment: The problem of looking for signatures in this case is that if we turn the can to the other side, i.e. hiding the signature, the algorithm will fail to detect the can.

Comment: @karlphillip: If you hide the signature, i.e. the logo, then *any* method based on looking for the logo is going to fail.

Comment: @Li-aungYip I'm aware of that, thank you. English is not my native language. :)

Comment: @karlphillip: I think what you may have meant to say is "imagine if you turn the can 90 degrees so that only *part* of the logo is visible." You can overcome that by taking three scan lines (top, middle and bottom of logo) - if any part of the logo is visible, you can see at least one of these.

Comment: @Li-aungYip Nice workaround, but the signature method has other limitations, for instance, if the label of the can is a little bit damaged or if the can is a little bit smashed, the detection will fail. The reality is that this question is a tough **research** problem. It's too complex and it's current format invites extended discussion. People don't realize that there are experts researching this type of thing in a daily basis. The problem ain't going to be solved in a SO thread.

Comment: @Li-aungYip True, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it is appropriate to this Q&A site. Well, we already discussed this subject a lot on meta, no reason to do it here again. My argument was ditched when a moderator said that if people liked it then we should keep it.

Comment: You could make this algorithm recognize the can's shape if you add some additional steps: if you signature is detected, have an array of lengths that you expect the can to find (and expect not to find) the red can at for a number of intervals over the signature's length. Scan down the signature line, then outwards, testing to see if the pixels are the expected color.

Comment: Additional thought: you'd probably need a set of signatures to make the shape detection work, because you can't assume that the can is facing directly towards the camera. You could also run *another* algorithm to find the midpoint of the face of the can, but that's probably going down a long, dark road ;)

Comment: Any idea what to Google if I want to build something using this approach?

Comment: @DiegoCerdanPuyol: that's a pretty wide open question. What i have described is a fairly elementary application of the field of "[Digital Image Processing](https://www.google.com/search?q=digital+image+processing)" for which you will find numerous books at [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?field-keywords=digital+image+processing). Start reading some of that literature and if you run into a specific roadblock, post a more specific question here on SO (but not in the comments).

Comment: @kmote What is the knowledge representation format used in "Digital Image Processing" to store the _signature_ in a useful format so I can correlate it on new images?

Comment: This is by far the best suggestion, and should be the solution to this question; its simple elegant, it breaks down looking at things, it found a hack inside the question, a shortcut into how we observe the world. And thats what is artificial vision recognition is all about.

Comment: -1: This approach is an ad-hoc "solution" which does neither work with other logos or object types. Before trying to come up with you own solution you should really have a look into the literature of logo recognition, object recognition or image classification.

Comment: @Stefan - I have great respect for the work you've done in logo recognition, but I just wanted to point out that my "solution" does in fact address the OP's specific question. He did not ask for a general solution; he wanted a *fast* solution satisfying the stated requirements. Sometimes, as experts, we are too quick to jump to the over-engineered solution, when a simple "ad-hoc" approach might get you there with a fraction of the effort. (But in principal, I should point out that my approach is indeed extensible, and could in theory be trained on any number of logos.)

Comment: Wouldn't you still need to check every single row/rows group in the whole image, *360 for every possible rotation, for this "line" identifier? I don't suppose artificial neural-net would help at all in this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't look for high frequencies in the red channel. Deep red = (1,0,0) and white=(1,1,1). So red doesn't change. It are the other components that change.

Comment: It's hardly worth mentioning but of course this general idea utterly fails on quaternion invariance and scale invariance.

Comment: @NoBugs: (Apologies for the extremely delayed response!) This requires a _single_ pass through every row of the image, because we're not checking against a single line identifier, but rather a rotation-adjusted _collection_ of identifiers. (See section on "signature scan lines".)

Comment: @Fattie: Actually, (although I had to look up the word "quaternion"!) I believe both of your assertions are incorrect. If you'll read the description more closely, you will note that this approach is both scale- and rotation-invariant. (And rotation in the z-axis, for the purposes of this approach, is equivalent to scaling.)

Comment: @kmote I see, you're saying that the training lines, are actually say **30 or so** "taken" at different angles.  So you are proposing to take (let's say) about 20 ? lines of the original, at perhaps 30 angles, being about 1000.  then you make (let's say) about 100 scan lines SL of the image.  so for each SL, the "matching red-white scan" could appear at: any scale / any location within SL.  so, in a handywavey way, we will solve that particular classic image recognition problem.  so you'd do 100,000 of those "linear scale/position invariant" handwave matches.

Comment: *"Wouldn't you still need to check every single row/rows group in the whole image,  for every possible [many] rotations, for this "line" identifier"*  FWIW yes, that's correct.  note that "every" rotation is meaningless, you'd just try your best with (say) 20, 50 or 100 rotations.  In this scheme, for each scan of the test image (let's say you took 100 of them from top to bottom), you have to try each of those 100 scans with each of the (say) 50 rotations, at each of the (say) 10 or 20 test lines across the logo.

Comment: (continuing that last comment) again noting that each linear line-test in this proposed scheme involves position/scale invariance, which would have to be solved somehow.

Comment: I love the elegance of this - a signature is so simple but genius.

Answer (score 182):

Fun problem: when I glanced at your bottle image I thought it was a can too. But, as a human, what I did to tell the difference is that I then noticed it was also a bottle...

So, to tell cans and bottles apart, how about simply scanning for bottles first? If you find one, mask out the label before looking for cans.

Not too hard to implement if you're already doing cans. The real downside is it doubles your processing time. (But thinking ahead to real-world applications, you're going to end up wanting to do bottles anyway ;-)

Comment: Yep I've thought about that too, but didn't have much time to do it. How would you recognize a bottle, since it's main part will look like a scaled can? I was thinking looking for the red plug as well and see if it's aligned with the bottled center, but that doesn't seem very robust.

Comment: If there is a red cap (or ring) parallel to the "Coca cola" it is most likely a bottle.

Comment: @linker How did you train your algorithm for cans? Did you have examples of cans? How about training with examples of bottles?

Comment: The strength of this algorithm is that you only need **one** template to train on, and then it applies all transformations to match it to other potential cans. I was using a binarized and contour-based version of this template to train, so the only difference between can and bottle would be the plug, but I'm afraid it would bring more false positives since the gravity center would be somewhere on the edge or outside of the bottle. It's worth giving it a try I guess. But that will double my processing time and I'm going to cry ;)

Comment: Essentially this is a reasonable direction. I'd phrase it slightly different: First find all candidates, and then for each candidate determine whether it's a bottle, a can, or something else.

Comment: I really like this approach! Unfortunately, it lacks for sufficient generalization, as _bottles are not the only plausible false positives that may be detected._ I've gone ahead and [rolled this into an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10272868/517815), because it was too much to comment on here. :)

Comment: Wow! I actually thought there were two cans on that picture. I thought that was a can in the bottle... Perhaps you shouldn't blame the algorithm for missing it, only for not detecting the other one.

Comment: This "answer" is just a comment at best. On the entire site, this is the "not an answer" with the highest number of upvotes.

Comment: This fails when they market the 'coca cola' keg.  A speaker dependant limited vocabulary is much easier than speaker independent unlimited vocabulary applications.  The same concepts apply to vision.

Answer (score 153):

Isn't it difficult even for humans to distinguish between a bottle and a can in the second image (provided the transparent region of the bottle is hidden)?

They are almost the same except for a very small region (that is, width at the top of the can is a little small while the wrapper of the bottle is the same width throughout, but a minor change right?)

The first thing that came to my mind was to check for the red top of bottle. But it is still a problem, if there is no top for the bottle, or if it is partially hidden (as mentioned above).

The second thing I thought was about the transparency of bottle. OpenCV has some works on finding transparent objects in an image. Check the below links.

- [OpenCV Meeting Notes Minutes 2012-03-19](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/2012#2012-03-19)
- [OpenCV Meeting Notes Minutes 2012-02-28](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/2012#2012-02-28)

Particularly look at this to see how accurately they detect glass:

- [OpenCV Meeting Notes Minutes 2012-04-24](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/2012#2012-04-24)

See their implementation result:

[image]

They say it is the implementation of the paper ["A Geodesic Active Contour Framework for Finding Glass" by K. McHenry and J. Ponce, CVPR 2006](http://www-cvr.ai.uiuc.edu/ponce_grp/publication/paper/cvpr06a.pdf).

It might be helpful in your case a little bit, *but problem arises again if the bottle is filled.*

So I think here, you can search for the transparent body of the bottles first or for a red region connected to two transparent objects laterally which is obviously the bottle. (When working ideally, an image as follows.)

[image]

Now you can remove the yellow region, that is, the label of the bottle and run your algorithm to find the can.

Anyway, this solution also has different problems like in the other solutions.

1. It works only if your bottle is empty. In that case, you will have to search for the red region between the two black colors (if the Coca Cola liquid is black).
2. Another problem if transparent part is covered.

But anyway, if there are none of the above problems in the pictures, this seems be to a better way.

Comment: +1 I thought about this and was in my way to implement this approach. However, @linker should share his set of images so we can try to do more educated guesses.

Comment: yeah.. i am too thinking it was good if there were more images.

Comment: Considering if we have only the labels for bottles / cans and none of the other distinguishing factors of bottle cap or transparency or can top/bottom - The width of the bottle is different than the width of the can.

Comment: What if a can is placed in front of the logo for the bottle?

Answer (score 59):

I really like [Darren Cook's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168923/517815) and [stacker's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10169025/517815) to this problem. I was in the midst of throwing my thoughts into a comment on those, but I believe my approach is too answer-shaped to not leave here.

In short summary, you've identified an algorithm to determine that a Coca-Cola logo is present at a particular location in space. You're now trying to determine, for arbitrary orientations and arbitrary scaling factors, a heuristic suitable for distinguishing Coca-Cola *cans* from other objects, inclusive of: *bottles*, *billboards*, *advertisements*, and *Coca-Cola paraphernalia* all associated with this iconic logo. You didn't call out many of these additional cases in your problem statement, but I feel they're vital to the success of your algorithm.

The secret here is determining what visual features a *can* contains or, through the negative space, what features are present for other Coke products that are not present for cans. To that end, [the current top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168923/517815) sketches out a basic approach for selecting "can" if and only if "bottle" is not identified, either by the presence of a bottle cap, liquid, or other similar visual heuristics.

The problem is this breaks down. A bottle could, for example, be empty and lack the presence of a cap, leading to a false positive. Or, it could be *a partial bottle* with additional features mangled, leading again to false detection. Needless to say, this isn't elegant, nor is it effective for our purposes.

To this end, the most correct selection criteria for cans appear to be the following:

- Is the shape of the object silhouette, as [you sketched out in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10168686/517815), correct? If so, +1.
- If we assume the presence of natural or artificial light, do we detect a chrome outline to the bottle that signifies whether this is made of aluminum? If so, +1.
- Do we determine that the [specular properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection) of the object are correct, relative to our light sources ([illustrative video link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQhtzQ-UVbc) on [light source detection](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/34/28314/01265865.pdf?arnumber=1265865))? If so, +1.
- Can we determine any other properties about the object that identify it as a can, including, but not limited to, the topological image skew of the logo, the orientation of the object, the juxtaposition of the object (for example, on a planar surface like a table or in the context of other cans), and the presence of a pull tab? If so, for each, +1.

Your classification might then look like the following:

- For each candidate match, if the presence of a Coca Cola logo was detected, draw a gray border.
- For each match over +2, draw a red border.

This visually highlights to the user what was detected, emphasizing weak positives that may, correctly, be detected as mangled cans.

The detection of each property carries a very different time and space complexity, and for each approach, a quick pass through http://dsp.stackexchange.com is more than reasonable for determining the most correct and most efficient algorithm for your purposes. My intent here is, purely and simply, to emphasize that *detecting if something is a can by invalidating a small portion of the candidate detection space* isn't the most robust or effective solution to this problem, and ideally, you should take the appropriate actions accordingly.

And hey, congrats on [the Hacker News posting!](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3846063) On the whole, this is a pretty terrific question worthy of the publicity it received. :)

Comment: That's an interesting approach which is at least worth a try, I really like your reasoning on the problem

Comment: This is kind of what I was thinking: don't rule out particular kinds of false positives. Rule in more features of what makes a coke can. But I'm wondering: what do you do about a squished can? I mean, if you step on a coke can it's still a coke can. But it won't have the same shape anymore. Or is that problem AI-Complete?

Answer (score 46):

**Looking at shape**

Take a gander at the shape of the red portion of the can/bottle. Notice how the can tapers off slightly at the very top whereas the bottle label is straight. You can distinguish between these two by comparing the width of the red portion across the length of it.

**Looking at highlights**

One way to distinguish between bottles and cans is the material. A bottle is made of plastic whereas a can is made of aluminum metal. In sufficiently well-lit situations, looking at the specularity would be one way of telling a bottle label from a can label.

As far as I can tell, that is how a human would tell the difference between the two types of labels. If the lighting conditions are poor, there is bound to be some uncertainty in distinguishing the two anyways. In that case, you would have to be able to detect the presence of the transparent/translucent bottle itself.

Comment: I like the idea, but it seems like you'd need some really really good lighting conditions. In the example image where there is both can and bottle for example this seems a bit hard to make the distinction.

Comment: In your example, notice how the specularity for the plastic label is much more diffuse than the very bright spots on the can? That's how you can tell.

Comment: I see, which kind of color space representation would you use in this case to capture specularity in your algorithm? This seems quite tough to get in RGB or HSV

Comment: What if the light source was behind the can? I think you would not see the highlight.

Answer (score 43):

Please take a look at Zdenek Kalal's [Predator tracker](https://web.archive.org/web/20121025151628/http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/Z.Kalal/tld.html). It requires some training, but it can actively learn how the tracked object looks at different orientations and scales and does it in realtime!

The source code is available on his site. It's in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), but perhaps there is a Java implementation already done by a community member. I have succesfully re-implemented the tracker part of TLD in C#. If I remember correctly, TLD is using Ferns as the keypoint detector. I use either SURF or SIFT instead (already suggested by @stacker) to reacquire the object if it was lost by the tracker. The tracker's feedback makes it easy to build with time a dynamic list of sift/surf templates that with time enable reacquiring the object with very high precision.

If you're interested in my C# implementation of the tracker, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the link that looks interesting. Regarding the training, what is the size of the training set that would be reasonable to achieve reasonable results? If you have an implementation even in c# that would be very helpful as well !

Comment: While researching TLD, I found another user looking for a C# implementation--- is there any reason not to put your work on Github?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436719/predator-tlk-algorithm-in-c-sharp

Comment: N.B. Years, later, link is now dead

Answer (score 40):

If you are not limited to just a camera which wasn't in one of your constraints perhaps you can move to using a range sensor like the Xbox [Kinect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect). With this you can perform depth and colour based matched segmentation of the image. This allows for faster separation of objects in the image. You can then use ICP matching or similar techniques to even match the shape of the can rather then just its outline or colour and given that it is cylindrical this may be a valid option for any orientation if you have a previous 3D scan of the target. These techniques are often quite quick especially when used for such a specific purpose which should solve your speed problem.

Also I could suggest, not necessarily for accuracy or speed but for fun you could use a trained neural network on your hue segmented image to identify the shape of the can. These are very fast and can often be up to 80/90% accurate. Training would be a little bit of a long process though as you would have to manually identify the can in each image.

Comment: Actually I didn't explain that in the post, but for this assignment I was given a set of roughly 30 images, and had to do an algorithm who would match them all in various situations as described. Of course some images were held out to test the algorithm in the end. But I like the idea of Kinect sensors, and I'd love to read more on the topic !

Comment: What would roughly be the size of the training set with a neural network to have satisfying results? What's nice with this method also is that I only need one template to match almost everything.

Comment: If your set of images is predefined and limited, just hardcore perfect results in your prog ;)

Comment: Yeah if I train on the dataset I'm going to run the algorithm against, sure I'll get perfect results :) But for example for this assignment, the program was tested by the teacher in the end on a set of held out images. I'd like to do something that would be robust and not overfit to the training data.

Comment: The number of training sets varies, you have to be careful of a few things though:
Don't over train, you probably want a test set to show how your accuracy is going.
Also the number of training sets will depend on the number of layers you will use.

Comment: Regarding neural networks in the context of shape recognition, do you know if there's something similar in OpenCV? Or if i'd need to implement my own?

Comment: You will probably want to implement your own. I have not seen anything in openCV.

Answer (score 29):

This may be a very naive idea (or may not work at all), but the dimensions of all the coke cans are fixed. So may be if the same image contains both a can and a bottle then you can tell them apart by size considerations (bottles are going to be larger). Now because of missing depth (i.e. 3D mapping to 2D mapping) its possible that a bottle may appear shrunk and there isn't a size difference. You may recover some depth information using [stereo-imaging](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/Vision_lecture/node11.html) and then recover the original size.

Comment: Actually no : there is no constraint of size or orientation (or orientation but i didn't really handle that), so you can have a bottle very far in the background, and a can in the foreground, and the can would be way bigger than the bottle.

Comment: I've also checked that the width to height ratio is pretty similar for bottle and can, so that's not really an option as well.

Comment: The label ratio (being it a trademark) is the same. So if the (bigger) bottle is slightly further away on the picture, its size will be exactly the same as that of the can.

Comment: Yes exactly that is why I suggest stereo imaging to recover the depth first. By using stereo imaging you can get the depth and then evaluate the actual size by adding the depth info.

Comment: To explain a bit more. Suppose can is at z=0 and bottle at z=-100. Since bottle is far behind it will look smaller. But if I know that the bottle is at z=-100 and can at z=0, then I can calculate the expected size of the can/bottle if both are translated to z=0. So now they are at the same depth and hence I can make decisions based on size.

Answer (score 29):

I would detect red rectangles: RGB -> HSV, filter red -> binary image, [close](http://undergraduate.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS4240/Lectures/morphology.pdf) (dilate then erode, known as `imclose` in matlab)

Then look through rectangles from largest to smallest. Rectangles that have smaller rectangles in a known position/scale can both be removed (assuming bottle proportions are constant, the smaller rectangle would be a bottle cap).

This would leave you with red rectangles, then you'll need to somehow detect the logos to tell if they're a red rectangle or a coke can. Like OCR, but with a known logo?

Comment: Like this was being discussed on DSP in the short time when it was moved, some bottles may not have plugs ;) or the plug could partially hidden.

Answer (score 26):

Hmm, I actually think I'm onto *something* (this is like the most interesting question ever - so it'd be a shame not to continue trying to find the "perfect" answer, even though an acceptable one has been found)...

Once you find the logo, your troubles are half done. Then you only have to figure out the differences between what's **around** the logo. Additionally, we want to do as little extra as possible. I think this is actually this easy part...

What *is* around the logo? For a can, we can see metal, which despite the effects of lighting, does not change whatsoever in its basic colour. As long as we know the angle of the label, we can tell what's directly above it, so we're looking at the difference between these:

[image]

Here, what's above and below the logo is completely dark, consistent in colour. Relatively easy in that respect.

[image]

Here, what's above and below is light, but still consistent in colour. It's all-silver, and all-silver metal actually seems pretty rare, as well as silver colours in general. Additionally, it's in a thin slither and close enough to the red that has already been identified so you could trace its shape for its entire length to calculate a percentage of what can be considered the metal ring of the can. Really, you only need a small fraction of that anywhere along the can to tell it is part of it, but you still need to find a balance that ensures it's not just an empty bottle with something metal behind it.

[image]

And finally, the tricky one. But not so tricky, once we're only going by what we can see directly above (and below) the red wrapper. Its transparent, which means it will show whatever is behind it. That's good, because things that are behind it aren't likely to be as consistent in colour as the silver circular metal of the can. There could be many different things behind it, which would tell us that it's an empty (or filled with clear liquid) bottle, or a consistent colour, which could either mean that it's filled with liquid or that the bottle is simply in front of a solid colour. We're working with what's closest to the top and bottom, and the chances of the right colours being in the right place are relatively slim. We know it's a bottle, because it hasn't got that key visual element of the can, which is relatively simplistic compared to what could be behind a bottle.

**(that last one was the best I could find of an empty large coca cola bottle - interestingly the cap AND ring are yellow, indicating that the redness of the cap probably shouldn't be relied upon)**

In the rare circumstance that a similar shade of silver is behind the bottle, even after the abstraction of the plastic, or the bottle is somehow filled with the same shade of silver liquid, we can fall back on what we can roughly estimate as being the shape of the silver - which as I mentioned, is circular and follows the shape of the can. But even though I lack any certain knowledge in image processing, that sounds slow. Better yet, why not deduce this by for once checking around the **sides** of the logo to ensure there is nothing of the same silver colour there? Ah, but what if there's the same shade of silver behind a can? Then, we do indeed have to pay more attention to shapes, looking at the top and bottom of the can again.

Depending on how flawless this all needs to be, it could be very slow, but I guess my basic concept is to check the easiest and closest things first. Go by colour differences around the already matched shape (which seems the most trivial part of this anyway) before going to the effort of working out the shape of the other elements. To list it, it goes:

- Find the main attraction (red logo background, and possibly the logo itself for orientation, though in case the can is turned away, you need to concentrate on the red alone)
- Verify the shape and orientation, yet again via the very distinctive redness
- Check colours around the shape (since it's quick and painless)
- Finally, if needed, verify the shape of those colours around the main attraction for the right roundness.

In the event you can't do this, it probably means the top and bottom of the can are covered, and the only possible things that a human could have used to reliably make a distinction between the can and the bottle is the occlusion and reflection of the can, which would be a **much** harder battle to process. However, to go even further, you could follow the angle of the can/bottle to check for more bottle-like traits, using the semi-transparent scanning techniques mentioned in the other answers.

Interesting additional nightmares might include a can conveniently sitting behind the bottle at such a distance that the metal of it just so happens to show above and below the label, which would still fail as long as you're scanning along the entire length of the red label - which is actually more of a problem because you're not detecting a can where you could have, as opposed to considering that you're actually detecting a bottle, including the can by accident. The glass is half empty, in that case!

---

As a disclaimer, I have no experience in nor have ever thought about image processing outside of this question, but it is so interesting that it got me thinking pretty deeply about it, and after reading all the other answers, I consider this to possibly be the easiest **and** most efficient way to get it done. Personally, I'm just glad I don't *actually* have to think about programming this!

**EDIT**

[image: bad drawing of a can in MS paint]
Additionally, look at this drawing I did in MS Paint... It's absolutely awful and quite incomplete, but based on the shape and colours alone, you can guess what it's probably going to be. In essence, these are the only things that one needs to bother scanning for. When you look at that very distinctive shape and combination of colours so close, what else could it possibly be? The bit I didn't paint, the white background, should be considered "anything inconsistent". If it had a transparent background, it could go over almost any other image and you could still see it.

Comment: The particular shade of red is mostly subjective and strongly influenced by lighting considerations and white balance. You might be surprised by how much those can change. Consider, for example, this [checkerboard illusion](http://web.mit.edu/persci/people/adelson/checkershadow_illusion.html).

Comment: An update to the link that @Octopus posted: http://persci.mit.edu/gallery/checkershadow

Comment: A perception illusion doesn’t affect what your webcam sees - i.e. what your code gets - only how a human eye helpfully(?) fools the brain.

Answer (score 25):

Am a few years late in answering this question. With the state of the art pushed to its limits by CNNs in the last 5 years I wouldn't use OpenCV to do this task now! (**I know you specifically wanted OpenCv features in the question**) I feel object detection algorithms such as Faster-RCNNs, YOLO, SSD etc would ace this problem with a significant margin compared to OpenCV features. If I were to tackle this problem now (after 6 years !!) I would definitely use **Faster-RCNN**.

Comment: OP said there were 30 high-res images, which is probably not the best scenario for training ConvNets. Not only are they too few (even augmented), the high-res part would destroy ConvNets.

Answer (score 22):

I'm not aware of OpenCV but looking at the problem logically I think you could differentiate between bottle and can by changing the image which you are looking for i.e. Coca Cola. You should incorporate till top portion of can as in case of can there is silver lining at top of coca cola and in case of bottle there will be no such silver lining.

But obviously this algorithm will fail in cases where top of can is hidden, but in such case even human will not be able to differentiate between the two (if only coca cola portion of bottle/can is visible)

Comment: I had the same thought, but I think the silver lining on top of the can changes dramatically depending on the angle of the can on the picture. It can be a straight line or a circle. Maybe he could use both as reference?

Answer (score 19):

I like the challenge and wanted to give an answer, which solves the issue, I think.

1. Extract features (keypoints, descriptors such as SIFT, SURF) of the logo
2. Match the points with a model image of the logo (using Matcher such as Brute Force )
3. Estimate the coordinates of the rigid body (PnP problem - SolvePnP)
4. Estimate the cap position according to the rigid body
5. Do back-projection and calculate the image pixel position (ROI) of the cap of the bottle (I assume you have the intrinsic parameters of the camera)
6. Check with a method whether the cap is there or not. If there, then this is the bottle

Detection of the cap is another issue. It can be either complicated or simple. If I were you, I would simply check the color histogram in the ROI for a simple decision.

Please, give the feedback if I am wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

**Deep Learning**

Gather at least a few hundred images containing cola cans, annotate the bounding box around them as positive classes, include cola bottles and other cola products label them negative classes as well as random objects.

Unless you collect a very large dataset, perform the trick of using deep learning features for small dataset. Ideally using a combination of Support Vector Machines(SVM) with deep neural nets.

Once you feed the images to a previously trained deep learning model(e.g. GoogleNet), instead of using neural network's decision (final) layer to do classifications, use previous layer(s)' data as features to train your classifier.

OpenCV and Google Net:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html

OpenCV and SVM:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html

Comment: Haha this is the most obvious answer that will probably perform best but its somewhere waaay down the list. Goes to show you the voting mechanism is not very reliable to separate the best/worst answers.

Answer (score 15):

I like your question, regardless of whether it's off topic or not :P

An interesting aside; I've just completed a subject in my degree where we covered robotics and computer vision. Our project for the semester was incredibly similar to the one you describe.

We had to develop a robot that used an Xbox Kinect to detect coke bottles and cans on any orientation in a variety of lighting and environmental conditions. Our solution involved using a band pass filter on the Hue channel in combination with the hough circle transform. We were able to constrain the environment a bit (we could chose where and how to position the robot and Kinect sensor), otherwise we were going to use the SIFT or SURF transforms.

You can read about our approach on [my blog post on the topic](http://elucidatedbinary.com/blog/2012/12/03/kinect/) :)

Comment: Interesting project but it only applies to your very specific setup.

Answer (score 13):

There are a bunch of color descriptors used to recognise objects, the paper below compares a lot of them. They are specially powerful when combined with SIFT or SURF. SURF or SIFT alone are not very useful in a coca cola can image because they don't recognise a lot of interest points, you need the color information to help. I use BIC (Border/Interior Pixel Classiﬁcation) with SURF in a project and it worked great to recognise objects.

[Color descriptors for Web image retrieval: a comparative study](http://sibgrapi.sid.inpe.br/col/sid.inpe.br/sibgrapi@80/2008/07.23.23.58/doc/penatti-ColorDescriptorsWeb.pdf)

Answer (score 13):

You need a program that learns and improves classification accuracy organically from experience.

I'll suggest deep learning, with deep learning this becomes a trivial problem.

You can retrain the inception v3 model on Tensorflow:

[How to Retrain Inception's Final Layer for New Categories](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining).

In this case, you will be training a convolutional neural network to classify an object as either a coca-cola can or not.

Answer (score 9):

As alternative to all these nice solutions, you can train your own classifier and make your application robust to errors. As example, you can use [Haar Training](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html), providing a good number of positive and negative images of your target.

It can be useful to extract only cans and can be combined with the detection of transparent objects.

Answer (score 6):

There is a computer vision package called HALCON from [MVTec](http://www.mvtec.com) whose demos could give you good algorithm ideas. There is plenty of examples similar to your problem that you could run in demo mode and then look at the operators in the code and see how to implement them from existing OpenCV operators.

I have used this package to quickly prototype complex algorithms for problems like this and then find how to implement them using existing OpenCV features. In particular for your case you could try to implement in OpenCV the functionality embedded in the operator [find_scaled_shape_model](http://www.halcon.com/download/reference/find_scaled_shape_model.html). Some operators point to the scientific paper regarding algorithm implementation which can help to find out how to do something similar in OpenCV.

Comment: HALCON is a proprietary software, is there any opensource packages which provides similar solutions than opencv.

Comment: If there were, MVTec would be out of business by now. Their software is really expensive!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe too many years late, but nevertheless a theory to try.

The ratio of bounding rectangle of red logo region to the overall dimension of the bottle/can is different. In the case of Can, should be 1:1, whereas will be different in that of bottle (with or without cap). 
This should make it easy to distinguish between the two.

Update:
The horizontal curvature of the logo region will be different between the Can and Bottle due their respective size difference. This could be specifically useful if your robot needs to pick up can/bottle, and you decide the grip accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in it being realtime, then what you need is to add in a pre-processing filter to determine what gets scanned with the heavy-duty stuff. A good fast, very real time, pre-processing filter that will allow you to scan things that are more likely to be a coca-cola can than not before moving onto more iffy things is something like this: search the image for the biggest patches of color that are a certain tolerance away from the `sqrt(pow(red,2) + pow(blue,2) + pow(green,2))` of your coca-cola can. Start with a very strict color tolerance, and work your way down to more lenient color tolerances. Then, when your robot runs out of an allotted time to process the current frame, it uses the currently found bottles for your purposes. Please note that you will have to tweak the RGB colors in the `sqrt(pow(red,2) + pow(blue,2) + pow(green,2))` to get them just right.

Also, this is gona seem really dumb, but did you make sure to turn on `-oFast` compiler optimizations when you compiled your C code?

Answer (score 3):

The first things I would look for are color - like RED , when doing Red eye detection in an image - there is a certain color range to detect , some characteristics about it considering the surrounding area and such as distance apart from the other eye if it is indeed visible in the image.

1: First characteristic is color and Red is very dominant. After detecting the Coca Cola Red there are several items of interest 
1A: How big is this red area (is it of sufficient quantity to make a determination of a true can or not - 10 pixels is probably not enough),
1B: Does it contain the color of the Label - "Coca-Cola"  or wave. 
1B1: Is there enough to consider a high probability that it is a label.

Item 1 is kind of a short cut - pre-process if that doe snot exist in the image - move on.

So if that is the case I can then utilize that segment of my image and start looking more zoom out of the area in question a little bit - basically look at the surrounding region / edges...

2: Given the above image area ID'd in 1 - verify the surrounding points [edges] of the item in question.
A: Is there what appears to be a can top or bottom - silver?
B: A bottle might appear transparent , but so might a glass table - so is there a glass table/shelf or a transparent area - if so there are multiple possible out comes. A Bottle MIGHT have a red cap, it might not, but it should have either the shape of the bottle top / thread screws, or a cap. 
C: Even if this fails A and B it still can be a can - partial..
This is more complex when it is partial because a partial bottle / partial can might look the same , so some more processing of measurement of the Red region edge to edge.. small bottle might be similar in size ..

3: After the above analysis that is when I would look at the lettering and the wave logo - because I can orient my search for some of the letters in the words As you might not have all of the text due to not having all of the can, the wave would align at certain points to the text (distance wise) so I could search for that probability and know which letters should exist at that point of the wave at distance x.