# Calculating a bottle height and two diameter with OpenCv- Edge Detection

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I have graduate project about calculate software with OpenCv. Firstly take a  grey photo with webcam  then detect the edge of bottle. The head and buttom side edge detect. Then calculate a value the bottle height with pixel. Getting reference form head and button, it take a and b value pixel then get diameters. Edge Detection method is not matter.

This picture can be more comprehensible for problem http://speedy.sh/vRgTy/w.JPG

I must get all values for different bottle and can with a OpenCv solution. I   How can I solve this problem? It would be very good if anybody give a hint to carry out this project.

Comment: Please add the picture here, not on a hosting site.  Also, please describe your current attempt at a solution (could be in pseudocode).  Also, please tag as homework.

Comment: i'd start with calibrating the cam(to get the fov), but if you know neither the distance, nor the height, - you're doomed!

Comment: Actually, I m new about OpenCv so I m researching what to do now. I m sorry I dont have enough reputation to upload photo.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a graduate project, you should probably do some reading in the literature. Specifically about object detection/recognition. There is a lot of literature out there on the topic, and [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/) can be your friend.

You should also take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168686/algorithm-improvement-for-coca-cola-can-shape-recognition?rq=1), there is a large amount of info there which is related to what you want to do.

Lastly, there is a wonderful free book on [Machine Vision](http://www.cse.usf.edu/~r1k/MachineVisionBook/MachineVision.pdf) you can read here, and they go into detail on object recognition in chapter 15.

Good Luck!