# opencv searching on image templates

Tags: opencv, pattern-matching

I have a database with images(templates) and I have a video stream. Is there any way of searching in this stream templates? I know that there is function matchTemplate but this function search identical image but my templates and the object on stream could be different size, color etc. Only proportion and shape are the same.

Comment: Have you gotten an error message, have you tried anything?

Comment: search on stackoverflow "object recognitioN", there are many questions and maybe some of the answers help you. try this one for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168686/algorithm-improvement-for-coca-cola-can-shape-recognition