# Central Object Extraction

Tags: image-processing, matlab, image-recognition, feature-extraction

Trying to determine if central object extraction is possible using Matlab and their Image Processing toolkit.

Want to match an image to another image. We need to extract an object from an image, using something like Central Object extraction. Once we have that image, we would like to compare to a library of objects and identify how close of a match we have to the image in the catalog.

Example: take a picture of an object that you are holding in your hand. We want to extract that object from your hand and then compare that extracted object to a catalog of images. The result would be a list of catalog items and a percentage of accuracy to that object.

Comment: Related: [Algorithm improvement for Coca-Cola can shape recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10168686/2545927)

Comment: Please post a sample image and a few images from the catalogue.