# Which template method do I use for template matching logos within an image?

Tags: opencv, image-recognition, template-matching

I've coded in a web service to match templates in the posted image and return the results. I'm using a .net wrapper for OpenCV with the CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED matching method. We're basically trying to match logos on pictures taken with a smartphone. Is this the best method to use and also, are there any techniques in terms of deciding on and optimising the image templates which would make the recognition process more accurate (we're getting around 60% success rate so far which needs to be improved).

Comment: I think you need to post some example images The selection of algorithm depends highly on the aim and the image characteristics. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10168686/2545927) should give you something to think about.

Comment: Some time has passed.  Are you still working on this?  Can you answer your own question now?