# Using SURF algorithm to match objects on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-detection, surf, matlab-cvst

The objective is to see if two images, which have one object captured in each image, matches.

The object or image I have stored. This will be used as a baseline:

- item1 (This is being matched in the code)

The object/image that needs to matched with-this is stored:

- input (Need to see if this matches with what is stored

My method:

1. Covert images to gray-scale.
2. Extract SURF interest points.
3. Obtain features.
4. Match features.
5. Get 50 strongest features.
6. Match the number of strongest features with each image.
7. Take the ratio of- number of features matched/ number of strongest
   features (which is 50).

If I have two images of the same object (two images taken separately on a camera), ideally the ratio should be near 1 or near 100%.
However this is not the case, the best ratio I am getting is near 0.5 or even worse, 0.3.

I am aware the SURF detectors and features can be used in neural networks, or using a statistics based approach. I believe I have approached the statistics based approach to some extent by using 50 of the strongest features.

Is there something I am missing? What do I add onto this or how do I improve it? Please provide me a point to start from.

```
%Clearing the workspace and all variables
clc;
clear;

%ITEM 1
item1 = imread('Loreal.jpg');%Retrieve order 1 and digitize it.
item1Grey  = rgb2gray(item1);%convert to grayscale, 2 dimensional matrix
item1KP = detectSURFFeatures(item1Grey,'MetricThreshold',600);%get SURF dectectors or interest points
strong1 = item1KP.selectStrongest(50);
[item1Features, item1Points] = extractFeatures(item1Grey, strong1,'SURFSize',128); % using SURFSize of 128

%INPUT : Aquire Image
input= imread('MakeUp1.jpg');%Retrieve input and digitize it.
inputGrey  = rgb2gray(input);%convert to grayscale, 2 dimensional matrix
inputKP = detectSURFFeatures(inputGrey,'MetricThreshold',600);%get SURF dectectors or interest
strongInput = inputKP.selectStrongest(50);
[inputFeatures, inputPoints] = extractFeatures(inputGrey, strongInput,'SURFSize',128); % using SURFSize of 128

pairs = matchFeatures(item1Features, inputFeatures, 'MaxRatio',1); %matching SURF Features
totalFeatures = length(item1Features); %baseline number of features
numPairs = length(pairs); %the number of pairs
percentage  = numPairs/50;

if percentage >= 0.49
    disp('We have this');
else
    disp('We do not have this');
    disp(percentage);
end
```

## The baseline image

[image]

## The input image

[image]

Comment: Could you post some sample images, please.

Comment: I uploaded the images using tinypic. There taken with the same camera-took the picture twice. They should return at least 90% using the ratio setup I have.

Comment: Thank you rayryeng for that picture edit. Much cleaner.

Comment: I believe the issue to the best of my understanding is whether using `matchFeatures` is the best effort or should a different algorithm be used. I was thinking about using BRISK, but `detectBRISKFeatures` is not recognized as a function in my 2013a version of MATLAB. Maybe using a other feature like FAST should be used with SURF points?

Comment: [Algorithm improvement for Coca-Cola can shape recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10168686/2545927) might be useful. There are answers that talk about SURF.

Answer (score 1):

I would try not doing `selectStrongest` and not setting `MaxRatio`.  Just call `matchFeatures` with the default options and compare the number of resulting matches.

The default behavior of `matchFeatures` is to use the ratio test to exclude ambiguous matches. So the number of matches it returns may be a good indicator of the presence or absence of the object in the scene.

If you want to try something more sophisticated, take a look at this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-search-using-point-features.html).

Comment: 'matchFeatures' would return a good number of pairs that correspond between two sets of features.
In order to see if the number of matched pairs is a good enough number of pairs, I compare to the number of pairs that the baseline image has. I take the ratio of that and the ratio I am getting is around 0.4 and 0.5. Is that good enough in terms of object matching  by using features?

Comment: I don't know. You are going to have to test the overall system, and tune the thresholds.

Comment: Tune the thresholds for the gray scale images or the thresholds for the point and feature functions? I tried only matching the strongest features (even tried 15), but the best ratio I could obtain was 0.5.

Comment: What I mean is that you need to check if the ratio greater than 0.4, for example, is sufficient to decide whether two images match or not.

Comment: It seems that the SURF algorithm implies that only one baseline image is needed to recognize an object. Is that really the case, because just one image of a object.. sounds not enough?