# Find small image coordinates within a large image

Tags: image, opencv, image-stitching

[image]
I have 2 images. 
One is a smaller version of the other and has also been cropped in all sides.
I need to find the exact location of the smaller image inside the large one.
Using OpenCV Homography function I managed to achieve it only if both images had the same scale:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography

For images with different scales, I suppose I need to downscale the large image to match the smaller one, but how can I find the scaling factor ?

Comment: e.g. by testing for "each" scaling factor in a loop.

Comment: Please add images to illustrate the problem.

Comment: You can also use a recognition approach, for instance as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10169025/1633399).

Comment: If you use SIFT or SURF (as in your link), it should work since the descriptors are scale-invariant.

Comment: how is this related to image-stitching?!