# Predator TLK Algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, opencv, tracking, emgucv

I've been looking for any updates regarding the robust Predator tracking algorithm that trains itself over time automatically

for those who are unfamiliar you can check [this](http://www.engadget.com/2011/03/31/zdenek-kalals-object-tracking-algorithm-learns-on-the-fly-like/)

I'm not sure if anyone was able to port it on C# since he originally developed it on matlab

here's the latest thing I came up to [TLD in OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/p/qopentld/wiki/Home/)

I'm looking for a C# port if anybody successfully made it possible

Thanks in advance!