# duplicate image detection in PHP with all comparisson parameters different

Tags: php, image, image-processing, duplicates

Is there anyway to detect image duplication in PHP, having the images:
- Different names;
- Different file sizes;
- Different image widths and heights?

Example as follows:

[image: Use case]

Comment: It's quite a big research project you are proposing. [Algorithm improvement for Coca-Cola can shape recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168686/algorithm-improvement-for-coca-cola-can-shape-recognition) might give you an insight into the difficulties...

Comment: @kkuilla: I'm aware it can be a bit tricky, but hoping for the existence of a (simple) solution for this specific case... In the example I gave there are 2 set of identical pics, the thing is someone just resized the original, changed file names and uploaded them again to the server, without altering the contents.

Comment: That is no easy thing. Besides, your question isn't very well defined. You are leaving a lot of guessing to the user. For example, I don't know how those pictures are different. Which ones are different? How are they different? Why are they different? You haven't explained that. Please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I thought that was easily understandable by looking at the data on the example printscreen. You can see there that the filenames are different, as is the file size, image width and image height.

Comment: It's easy for you who know exactly what you are looking for. It is a completely different thing for somebody who has no prior knowledge of your problem/application, reads your two lines of text and see four images. Most people ignore questions where it takes effort to understand the problem. ***Make it easy for people to understand and replicate your issue.*** That's why is it always good to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) even if it requires lots of work but you will have a much higher chance of getting a useful answer if you do.