# Finding the American flag in a picture?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

In honor of the Fourth of July, I was interested in finding a programmatic way to detect the American flag in a picture. There is an [earlier and popular question about finding Coca-Cola cans in images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168686/image-processing-algorithm-improvement-for-coca-cola-can-recognition) that describes a number of good techniques for that problem, though I'm not sure that they'll work for flags because

1. flags flutter in the wind and therefore might occlude themselves or otherwise deform nonlinearly (which makes techniques like SIFT a bit harder to use), and
2. unlike a Coca-Cola can, the American flag's Stars and Stripes are not unique to the American flag and could be part of, say, the [flag of Liberia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Liberia.svg), ruling out many "line signature" techniques.

Are there any standard image processing or recognition techniques that would be particularly suited to this task?

Comment: If you have a large dataset for training, search for: deep learning image classification.   There has been great progress on this front in recent years.

Comment: I know that you are a well-known member of SO, but it looks like 1) no attempt was given. 2) the question is too broad.

Comment: @SalvadorDali, dude he answered his own question below. Good answer too (I just made it 16th upvotes). I think Asker is open to more answers / approaches though.

Comment: @VC.One dude, where exactly have you seen him answering his question?The guy who wrote a good answer is completely another guy.

Comment: @SalvadorDali, my bad, I thought from the timestamp of your comment you were responding to the Bounty Asker. It's all so surreal...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

My approach generalizes the problem and in fact looks for a red and white strips pattern (horizontal or vertical) near to a blue region. Therefore it works for scenes that only the American flag has this pattern.

My approach is developed in Java and uses [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/).

**Algorithm:**

1. Color filter for keeping only pixels with the same color of American flag.
2. Find horizontal red and white strips pattern
3. Find vertical red and white strips pattern
4. Remove patterns with small area (noise)
5. Check whether this pattern is surrounded by a blue region
6. Segment the area.

**Input:**

[image]

**Color Filter:**

[image]

**Flag:**

[image]

More interesting is the performance in the case there are many flags.

**Input**:

[image]

**Color Filter:**

[image]

**Pattern Matching:**

[image]

**Flag:**

[image]

**Source Code:**

```
import static marvin.MarvinPluginCollection.*;

public class AmericanFlag {

    public AmericanFlag(){
        process("./res/flags/", "flag_0", Color.yellow);
        process("./res/flags/", "flag_1", Color.yellow);
        process("./res/flags/", "flag_2", Color.yellow);
        process("./res/flags/", "flag_3", Color.yellow);
        process("./res/flags/", "flag_4", Color.blue);
    }

    private void process(String dir, String fileName, Color color){
        MarvinImage originalImage = MarvinImageIO.loadImage(dir+fileName+".jpg");
        MarvinImage image = originalImage.clone();
        colorFilter(image);
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(image, dir+fileName+"_color.png");

        MarvinImage output = new MarvinImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        output.clear(0xFFFFFFFF);
        findStripsH(image, output);
        findStripsV(image, output);
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(output, dir+fileName+"_1.png");

        MarvinImage bin = MarvinColorModelConverter.rgbToBinary(output, 127);
        morphologicalErosion(bin.clone(), bin, MarvinMath.getTrueMatrix(5, 5));
        morphologicalDilation(bin.clone(), bin, MarvinMath.getTrueMatrix(15, 15));
        MarvinImageIO.saveImage(bin, dir+fileName+"_2.png");

        int[] centroid = getCentroid(bin);
        image.fillRect(centroid[0], centroid[1], 30, 30, Color.yellow);

        int area = getMass(bin);
        boolean blueNeighbors = hasBlueNeighbors(image, bin, centroid[0], centroid[1], area);

        if(blueNeighbors){
            int[] seg = getSegment(bin);
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
                originalImage.drawRect(seg[0]+i, seg[1]+i, seg[2]-seg[0], seg[3]-seg[1], color);
            }
            MarvinImageIO.saveImage(originalImage, dir+fileName+"_final.png");
        }
    }

    private boolean hasBlueNeighbors(MarvinImage image, MarvinImage bin, int centerX, int centerY, int area){
        int totalBlue=0;
        int r,g,b;
        int maxDistance =  (int)(Math.sqrt(area)*1.2);
        for(int y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++){
                r = image.getIntComponent0(x, y);
                g = image.getIntComponent1(x, y);
                b = image.getIntComponent2(x, y);

                if(
                    (b == 255 && r == 0 && g == 0) &&
                    (MarvinMath.euclideanDistance(x, y, centerX, centerY) < maxDistance)
                ){
                    totalBlue++;
                    bin.setBinaryColor(x, y, true);
                }
            }
        }

        if(totalBlue > area/5){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private int[] getCentroid(MarvinImage bin){
        long totalX=0, totalY=0, totalPixels=0;
        for(int y=0; y<bin.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=0; x<bin.getWidth(); x++){

                if(bin.getBinaryColor(x, y)){
                    totalX += x;
                    totalY += y;
                    totalPixels++;
                }
            }
        }

        totalPixels = Math.max(1, totalPixels);
        return new int[]{(int)(totalX/totalPixels), (int)(totalY/totalPixels)};
    }

    private int getMass(MarvinImage bin){
        int totalPixels=0;
        for(int y=0; y<bin.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=0; x<bin.getWidth(); x++){
                if(bin.getBinaryColor(x, y)){
                    totalPixels++;
                }
            }
        }

        return totalPixels;
    }

    private int[] getSegment(MarvinImage bin){
        int x1=-1, x2=-1, y1=-1, y2=-1;
        for(int y=0; y<bin.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=0; x<bin.getWidth(); x++){
                if(bin.getBinaryColor(x, y)){

                    if(x1 == -1 || x < x1){ x1 = x; }
                    if(x2 == -1 || x > x2){ x2 = x; }
                    if(y1 == -1 || y < y1){ y1 = y; }
                    if(y2 == -1 || y > y2){ y2 = y; }
                }
            }
        }
        return new int[]{x1,y1,x2,y2};
    }

    private void findStripsH(MarvinImage imageIn, MarvinImage imageOut){

        int strips=0;
        int totalPixels=0;
        int r,g,b;
        int patternStart;
        boolean cR=true;
        int patternLength = -1;
        for(int y=0; y<imageIn.getHeight(); y++){
            patternStart = -1;
            strips = 0;
            patternLength=-1;
            for(int x=0; x<imageIn.getWidth(); x++){
                r = imageIn.getIntComponent0(x, y);
                g = imageIn.getIntComponent1(x, y);
                b = imageIn.getIntComponent2(x, y);

                if(cR){
                    if(r == 255 && g == 0 && b == 0){
                        if(patternStart == -1){ patternStart = x;}
                        totalPixels++;
                    } else{
                        if(patternLength == -1){
                            if(totalPixels >=3 && totalPixels <= 100){
                                patternLength = (int)(totalPixels);
                            } else{
                                totalPixels=0; patternStart=-1; strips=0; patternLength=-1;
                            }
                        } else{
                            if(totalPixels >= Math.max(patternLength*0.5,3) && totalPixels <= patternLength * 2){
                                strips++;
                                totalPixels=1;
                                cR = false;
                            } else{
                                totalPixels=0; patternStart=-1; strips=0; patternLength=-1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(r == 255 && g == 255 && b == 255){
                        totalPixels++;
                    } else{
                        if(totalPixels >= Math.max(patternLength*0.5,3) && totalPixels <= patternLength * 2){
                            strips++;
                            totalPixels=1;
                            cR = true;
                        } else{
                            totalPixels=0; patternStart=-1; strips=0; patternLength=-1; cR=true;
                        }
                    }
                }


                if(strips >= 4){
                    imageOut.fillRect(patternStart, y, x-patternStart, 2, Color.black);
                    totalPixels=0; patternStart=-1; strips=0; patternLength=-1; cR=true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void findStripsV(MarvinImage imageIn, MarvinImage imageOut){

        int strips=0;
        int totalPixels=0;
        int r,g,b;
        int patternStart;
        boolean cR=true;
        int patternLength = -1;
        for(int x=0; x<imageIn.getWidth(); x++){
            patternStart = -1;
            strips = 0;
            patternLength=-1;
            for(int y=0; y<imageIn.getHeight(); y++){
                r = imageIn.getIntComponent0(x, y);
                g = imageIn.getIntComponent1(x, y);
                b = imageIn.getIntComponent2(x, y);

                if(cR){
                    if(r == 255 && g == 0 && b == 0){
                        if(patternStart == -1){ patternStart = y;}
                        totalPixels++;
                    } else{
                        if(patternLength == -1){
                            if(totalPixels >=3 && totalPixels <= 100){
                                patternLength = (int)(totalPixels);
                            } else{
                                totalPixels=0; patternStart=-1; strips=0; patternLength=-1;
                            }
                        } else{
                            if(totalPixels >= Math.max(patternLength*0.5,3) && totalPixels <= patternLength * 2){
                                strips++;
                                totalPixels=1;
                                cR = false;
                            } else{
                                totalPixels=0; patternStart=-1; strips=0; patternLength=-1;
                            }
                        }
                    }

//                  if(maxL != -1 && totalPixels > maxL){
//                      totalPixels=0; patternStart=-1; strips=0; maxL=-1;
//                  }
                }
                else{
                    if(r == 255 && g == 255 && b == 255){
                        totalPixels++;
                    } else{
                        if(totalPixels >= Math.max(patternLength*0.5,3) && totalPixels <= patternLength * 2){
                            strips++;
                            totalPixels=1;
                            cR = true;
                        } else{
                            totalPixels=0; patternStart=-1; strips=0; patternLength=-1; cR=true;
                        }
                    }

//                  if(maxL != -1 &&  totalPixels > maxL){
//                      totalPixels=0; patternStart=-1; strips=0; maxL=-1;
//                      cR=true;
//                  }
                }


                if(strips >= 4){
                    imageOut.fillRect(x, patternStart, 2, y-patternStart, Color.black);
                    totalPixels=0; patternStart=-1; strips=0; patternLength=-1; cR=true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void colorFilter(MarvinImage image){

        int r,g,b;
        boolean isR, isB;
        for(int y=0; y<image.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=0; x<image.getWidth(); x++){
                r = image.getIntComponent0(x, y);
                g = image.getIntComponent1(x, y);
                b = image.getIntComponent2(x, y);

                isR = (r > 120 && r > g * 1.3 && r > b * 1.3);
                isB = (b > 30 && b < 150 && b > r * 1.3 && b > g * 1.3);

                if(isR){
                    image.setIntColor(x, y, 255,0,0);
                } else if(isB){
                    image.setIntColor(x, y, 0,0,255);
                } else{
                    image.setIntColor(x, y, 255,255,255);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AmericanFlag();
    }
}
```

**Other Results:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: But you didn't test it with the "flag of Liberia"... or is that the new challenge?

Comment: Most of the examples seem like they have neither the horizontal nor vertical stripes described by the algorithm - more like diagonal. Is this just a discrepancy in the way you worded your algorithm? Are you really looking specifically for horizontal or vertical stripes, or any orientation? Or are you somehow merging the horizontal and vertical to find diagonal?

Comment: In fact they have. Let me define this pattern in another way: a color alternation between red and white in the horizontal or vertical direction. A flag rotated 45 degrees, for instance, have both vertical and horizontal stripes pattern. If you cross the American flag with a line NOT PARALLEL to the stripes you'll see alternation between red and white. But, the pattern will be more intense when this line is orthogonal to the stripes. Yes, I merged horizontal and vertical results.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'Template Matching' via the OpenCV library.

Here is the Theory behind the approach:

> Template Matching is a method for searching and finding the location
>   of a template image in a larger image. OpenCV comes with a function
>   cv2.matchTemplate() for this purpose. It simply slides the template
>   image over the input image (as in 2D convolution) and compares the
>   template and patch of input image under the template image.

Code examples and implementation explanation can be found here:
http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html#gsc.tab=0