# How to find similar icons in one image and their positions in the original image

Tags: python, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I have an image and there are several similar icons in it; I want to find there positions (coordinates) in the original image.

My initial idea was to extract features from the image and cluster them, but I have no idea how to start it. Any suggestions for me?

The comment mentioned 【Template Matching】 , if I dont know what template is, how can I detect template before I matched?

Sample input image as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wnf0.png)

Comment: just use open-cv's template matching https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

Comment: Template matching would not work easily since it is sensitive to rotation and scale of the items.

Comment: Do you have those individual icon images?  If so, get the average color of the icon. Then threshold your image so that the icons are white and the background is black. Then get contours. From the contours use cv2.minAreaRect to get the rotated rectangle for each. Then get the average color inside the rotated rectangle and match that to the closest average color of your icons.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods to attack this problem.

- Maybe you can refactor this one: [pyimagesearch OCR](https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/17/credit-card-ocr-with-opencv-and-python/)
- **This thread is pretty cool** [coca cola pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168686/image-processing-algorithm-improvement-for-coca-cola-can-recognition?rq=1)
- This is the above but well explained [pyimagesearch Coca Cola](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/03/22/opencv-template-matching-cv2-matchtemplate/)
- Also a quick search in the web you can find multiple papers attacking this problem such as [Deep Learning for Logo Recognition](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.02620.pdf)

> if I dont know what template is, how can I detect template before I matched?

This question is hard. You should try to segment the logos and then use your known templates to see which one matches. Segmenting a logo in the wild is extremely hard. But if you are in the context of the example image you gave, it may be easier to use `cv.findCountours` and iterate through all.